# How to read/write "/sys/bus/pci/devices/.../resource2" in linux kernel or kernel module?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kernel, linux-device-driver, kernel-module

I am a green hand in linux kernel writing. I have two kvm virtual machines in qemu. I add a ivshmem for each, and they can use `open` and `mmap` function to read/write  `/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:00:05.0/resource2` to sync memory. Here is a reference: https://liujunming.top/2021/11/30/QEMU-tutorial-Inter-VM-Shared-Memory-device/

```
# QEMU parameters:
    -object memory-backend-file,size=4M,share=on,mem-path=/dev/shm/shm1,id=shm1 \
    -device ivshmem-plain,memdev=shm1,addr=0x05,master=on
```

However, I need to sync memory in kernel but not user space. I use linux kernel 5.10.20. There are two functions `kernel_read` and `kernel_write`. I can use the two functions to read/write a normal file such as `/home/xxx/a.txt`, but I cannot read/write `/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:00:05.0/resource2`.

Here is my code to read the first character:

```c
char buf_2[1];

void read_file(const char *filename)
{
    ssize_t i;
    struct file *f = NULL;
    loff_t f_pos = 0;

    f = filp_open(filename, O_RDWR, 0);
    if (IS_ERR(f)) {
        pr_err("open file error!\n");
    }

    memset(buf_2, 0, sizeof(buf_2));
    i = kernel_read(f, buf_2, 1, &f_pos);
    pr_info("f: %p, f_pos: %lld, buf_2: %d, i: %ld", f, f_pos, buf_2[0], i);

    filp_close(f, NULL);
}
```

When I pass `/home/xxx/a.txt` and `/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:00:05.0/resource2` to the `read_file`, it prints this:

```
[   40.154424] f: 00000000cad673bc, f_pos: 1, buf_2: 115, i: 1
[   40.154457] f: 0000000047ddc318, f_pos: 0, buf_2: 0, i: -5
```

The first result is corrent. But the second is not. And `kernel_read` returns a error code `-5`.

How can I read/write `/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:00:05.0/resource2` in linux kernel?

```sh
$ ls /sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:00:05.0/
ari_enabled               driver_override  msi_bus    resource2_wc
broken_parity_status      enable           numa_node  revision
class                     firmware_node    power      subsystem
config                    irq              remove     subsystem_device
consistent_dma_mask_bits  link             rescan     subsystem_vendor
d3cold_allowed            local_cpulist    resource   uevent
device                    local_cpus       resource0  vendor
dma_mask_bits             modalias         resource2

$ cat /sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:00:05.0/resource
0x00000000c1031000 0x00000000c10310ff 0x0000000000040200
0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000
0x0000001000000000 0x00000010003fffff 0x000000000014220c
0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000
0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000
0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000
0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000
```

Comment: _resource*_ files are the representations of the PCI BARs IIUC, so it means that you just need to find a PCI device and get its resources: `struct pci_dev *pdev = pci_get_domain_bus_and_slot(0, 0, PCI_DEVFN(5, 0)); struct resource *res = &pdev->resource[2]; dev_info(&pdev->dev, "%pR\n", res); pci_dev_put(pdev)`.

Comment: Couple of important notes: 1) opening files in the kernel is a bad idea; 2) *writing* to that file is not a simple operation — one needs to be quite aware of how PCI bus resource management works.